# Recording a webcam using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, camera

I'm struggling with ffmpeg. My webcam can do 720p at 30fps, but only when using the MJPEG codec:

```
~> v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
        Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)


-- cut -- 

                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.133 s (7.500 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200 s (5.000 fps)
-- cut --

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
        Name        : MJPEG


-- cut -- 
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033 s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040 s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050 s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067 s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100 s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200 s (5.000 fps)

-- cut --
```

I can't figure out how to tell ffmpeg to read the MJPEG compressed format. It is trying to read the raw variant, which ends up with horrible quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what options you're using but I did find these 2 examples. Do these work for you?

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -vcodec mjpeg -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -o <output_file.avi>
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -vcodec mjpeg -qscale 1 <output_file.avi>
```

For the second example, I found a note that mentioned that the `-qscale ...` switch made a noticeable difference. The lower your x, the better is the quality (range 2 to 32, fractions allowed).

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I already tried that, but it would seem that this is actually correct. It's just my webcam being incredibly temperamental (starts recording once out of five attempts).